# Getting JSON and evaluating data with just javascript

Tags: javascript, json

For instance I need to get the values from https://steamgaug.es/api and evaluate so if ISteamClient and ISteamFriends are 0 then a value of true for one boolean and if ISteamUser is 0 then another boolean is true.

I am completely new to this and the methods I have attempted haven't worked.

---

```
    function getJSONP(url, success) {

    var ud = '_' + +new Date,
        script = document.createElement('script'),
        head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] 
               || document.documentElement;

    window[ud] = function(data) {
        head.removeChild(script);
        success && success(data);
    };

    script.src = url.replace('callback=?', 'callback=' + ud);
    head.appendChild(script);

}

getJSONP('https://steamgaug.es/api&format=js&callback=?', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

But being completely new to JSON I'm not sure how to evaluate to responses..

Comment: please post some json data you received from ajax request

Comment: {
 "ISteamClient": 0,
 "ISteamFriends": 0,
 "ISteamUser": 0,
 "IEconItems_440": 6,
 "IEconItems_730": 0,
 "ISteamGameCoorindator_440": 0,
 "ISteamGameCoorindator_570": 0,
 "SteamCommunity": 3
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.getJSON( "test.json", function( data ) {
            var items = [];
            var ISteamClient=0,ISteamFriends=0,ISteamUser=0;
            $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                console.log("Key = "+key+" and Value = "+val);
                if(key==="ISteamClient")
                {
                    ISteamClient=val;
                }
                else if(key==="ISteamFriends")
                {
                    ISteamFriends=val;
                }
                else if(key==="ISteamUser")
                {
                    ISteamUser=val;
                }
            });

            if(ISteamClient==0&&ISteamFriends==0)
            {
                //do your things
            }
            if(ISteamUser==0)
            {
                //do your things
            }
        });
```

Comment: That is *terrible* code.  You loop through an object, looking for a key?  [That's not how this works!](http://i.lvme.me/pzv5j7l.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

With any modern browser you could write

```
getJSONP('https://steamgaug.es/api&format=js&callback=?', function(data) {
     data = JSON.parse(data);
     var firstValue = !data.ISteamClient;
     var secondValue = !data.ISteamFriends;
...
});
```

Comment: Where exactly would I put this?

Comment: The only place you have `data`: inside the getJSONP callback function.